# Lucene: how to assign and/or search

Tags: lucene

I want to search two queries at the same time, such as "macbook pro" and "iphone", and the default field to search is "title", so the query is :(title: macbook pro title:iphone). I want to use "and" operation within each query, e.g. (+title:macbook +title:pro), and "or" operation between querys,i.e.
((+title:macbook +title:pro) (title:iphone)). However, after using QueryParser to parse this query(title: macbook pro title:iphone), the result will be :(title: macbook title:pro title:iphone), if I set the default operator of parser is QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR, then the query will be (+title:macbook +title:pro +title:iphone). Neither is I need. What can I do to get the right query?((+title:macbook +title:pro) (title:iphone))

Comment: What is the problem with "((+title:macbook +title:pro) (title:iphone))"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achive this using QueryParser parameters but you can construct your query  programmatically using [BooleanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html) in Lucene API

Similar question: 
[How to create nested boolean query with lucene API (a AND (b OR c))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130908/how-to-create-nested-boolean-query-with-lucene-api-a-and-b-or-c)