# Cannot find TermsFilter class in Lucene.NET 3.0.3

Tags: c#, .net, search, lucene

I downloaded the latest nuget for [Lucene.NET](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet) 3.0.3 (stable, not the 4.0 beta) and I simply cannot find [TermsFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867570/how-to-implement-search-with-multiple-filters-using-lucene-net) in any of the releases.

It appears to be within the repo:

- [Link to the TermsFilter source](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/Lucene.Net.Queries/TermsFilter.cs) on github
- [Link to the docs](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/dir_5b88ab0c8cbeaf4a220fc00c661714a3.html) on apache.org

Some users have recommended looking in the "lucene-contrib.jar" but those instructions are for the original Java Lucene. The .NET version has no "contribs" release so I don't know how to find those classes.

So where can I find TermsFilter for Lucene.NET 3.0.3? Do I have to build from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine. I found it released on nuget inside the [Lucene.Net.Contrib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Contrib/3.0.3) package.