# Index multiple authors per book using Lucene.NET

Tags: c#, search, indexing, lucene, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.NET to build a search index of 10 million+ books. I am using this to index a book:

```
Document doc = new Document();

doc.Add(new Field("id", bookID, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));

doc.Add(new Field("publisher", publisherName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

doc.Add(new Field("title", bookTitle, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

**Search by Publisher:**

Since I've indexed book publishers with `Index.NOT_ANALYZED`, I can use the high-performance [TermsFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24075955/1294758) to do the equivalent of:

> SELECT * FROM books WHERE publisher="O'Reilly Media"

**Search by Title:**

And of course since I've indexed the book titles using the `Index.ANALYZED` option, I can use the standard QueryParser to do the equivalent of:

> SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE "%skating%"

**Search by Author:**

However now I need to search by author. I need something like:

> SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE "%skating%" AND authors CONTAIN "Jack Black"

So how do I go about doing that? I have both author names and author IDs stored per book. How can I index that into the Lucene Document and then quickly search for all books by author? I don't want to use SQL since I need to combine the search keywords with the author filter, so Lucene must do the author filtering for me.

The most obvious solution is:

```
doc.Add(new Field("authors", "Jack Black; Joan White", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

But this would incorrectly return books where the name of one author is similar/within the name of another author, eg:

- Book 1 : Authors : Jack D Black, Bob A Smith
- Book 2 : Authors : D Black

So at this point searching for "D Black" would incorrectly return Book 1 and Book 2, instead of just Book 2. I need to therefore index the whole author name or ID (using `Index.NOT_ANALYZED`), but I need multiple of such fields per book. Is this possible?

```
// can I add the same field multiple times into a document?
doc.Add(new Field("author", "Jack D Black", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("author", "Bob A Smith", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
```

Or I could add the author IDs, such that the analyzer takes each number as an independent word:

```
doc.Add(new Field("authors", "125;1885;23", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

And then use a regular Lucene search to find all books with the author "125"... Would this work or would this also list books with the author "1254"?

Comment: So why don't you just add an `author` field and then query on that?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - Question edited to reflect...

Comment: Oh I see. Yes you can add the same field multiple times, Lucene will index each value (I guess it's also true for Lucene.Net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lucas I figured you can add the same field multiple times during indexing:

```
foreach (string author in authors){
   doc.Add(new Field("author", author, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
}
```

This allows you to use the high-performance TermsFilter for searching exact matches.